# Angular sort by a calculated value

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-directive

I have an app where I display a list of elements, every one with different properties, and one of those properties is used to get another value from a factory, and I want to be able to sort the list by that calculated value.

I know I can save the calculated value in the list and then sort, but is that the only way?

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danaya/9n4d8faw/1/) and the code

```
angular
  .module("app", [])
  .controller('Controller', Controller)
  .factory('factory', factory)
  .directive('val', val)
  .controller('ValController', ValController)

  DirectiveController.$inject = [ 'factory'];

function Controller() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.results = [{
    "id": "1",
    "pos": 1
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "pos": 2
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "pos": 3
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "pos": 4
  }];

  console.info(JSON.stringify(vm.results));
}

function val() {
    return {
            replace: true,
            scope: {},
            bindToController: {
                id: '@'             
            },
            controller: ValController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',         
            template: '<td ng-bind="vm.value"></td>'
        };
}

function ValController(factory) {

    var vm = this;

  vm.value = factory.getValue(vm.id);
}

function factory() {

  var values = {
    '1': 'green',
    '2': 'blue',
    '3': 'yellow',
    '4': 'red'
  };

  return {
    getValue: function(id) {
      return values[id];
    }
  }
}
```

And a simple html

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>pos</th>
        <th>value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results | orderBy:'+value'">
        <td ng-bind="result.id"></td>
        <td ng-bind="result.pos"></td>
        <td val id="{{result.id}}"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this since the property value itself isn't reflective of sort there are numerous ways to do this. Short of modifying the items themselves with another property all will require sorting yourself in one place or another

A custom filter is convenient since you can inject the factory into it. Since the filter is used on an array, return a sorted array based on the value mapping from factory to item

```
.filter('valueSort',function(factory){    
     return function(items){
        if(!items) return;
        return items.sort(function(a, b){
            return factory.values[a.pos] > factory.values[b.pos];
        });        
     }  
});
```

View

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results | valueSort">
```

Note: I tweaked the factory to return your `values` object reference for demo

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/9n4d8faw/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: As far as I understand, this filter is retrieving the values from the factory again, so in terms of efficiency, wouldn´t it be faster to just store the values in my items in the first place and then sort as usual?

Comment: no real efficiency difference. The factory connection is no more than passing an object reference and the custom filter is no less efficient than orderBy which you would have to still use